# React push data into object of arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, import-from-excel

How do I get imported data from importFile.js into dataTable.js?

https://github.com/Romson/CSV-file-uploader/blob/master/src/components/importFile.js
https://github.com/Romson/CSV-file-uploader/blob/master/src/components/dataTable.js

Tried this function to change nested arrays in imported data from importFile.js  into a object of arrays.

```
const newArray = [data].map(
  ([firstName, lastName, issueCount, dateOfBirth]) => ({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    issueCount,
    dateOfBirth
  })
);
```

Then a push into dataTable.js with:

```
data.rows.push(newArray);
```

What is the correct way to do this in React?

Expected result is to get the imported data to show in this table:

https://csv-file-uploader.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Why would you map over a single-element array you *just* created?!

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe This was to convert the nested arrays into an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make DataTable component a child of Reader component. You need the array of object from Reader component for the rows property of datatable in DataTable component. As you said you are a beginner so better start from react hooks as it is easy.

**Reader component**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import CSVReader from "react-csv-reader";
import DatatablePage from "./dataTable";
import "../index.css";

const Reader = () =>  { 
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
return (
  <div className="container">
    <CSVReader
      cssClass="react-csv-input"
      label="Upload a new CSV file"
      onFileLoaded={(data) => setData(data)}
    />
    <DatatablePage uploadedData={data} />
  </div>
);
}

export default Reader;
```

**DatatablePage component**

```
import React from "react";
import { MDBDataTable } from "mdbreact";

const DatatablePage = ({uploadedData}) => {
  const data = {
    columns: [
      {
        label: "First Name",
        field: "name",
        sort: "asc",
        width: 150
      },
      {
        label: "Last Name",
        field: "surname",
        sort: "asc",
        width: 270
      },
      {
        label: "Issue count",
        field: "issuecount",
        sort: "asc",
        width: 200
      },
      {
        label: "Date of birth",
        field: "dateofbirth",
        sort: "asc",
        width: 100
      }
    ],
    rows: []
  };
// we append the passed props in the rows. read about spread operator if unaware of it.

const datatableProps = {...data, rows: uploadedData}; 
  return <MDBDataTable striped bordered hover uploadedData={uploadedData} data={datatableProps} />;
};

export default DatatablePage;
```

We are using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to create a state variable named data and a setter for it. Then we pass this state variable to the child component which can render it.

Comment: Thank @Kamlesh but unfortunately this breaks the sorting functionality in the table after a file has been uploaded. How can this be fixed in React App?